# Exibir campo sexo select box com outro valor

Tags: php

Estou tentando exibir o resultado do meu campo sexo com outro valor. No banco ta como F e  M mas no meu editar eu gostaria que o resultado aparece como masculino ou feminino. Tentei com `if-else` mas não consegui. Minha `div` é esta:

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="ds_sexo"> Sexo</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="ds_sexo"id="ds_sexo">
   <option value="<?=$cliente->ds_sexo?>"><?=$cliente->ds_sexo?>//aqui que eu gostaria que aparecer  masculino ou feminino dependendo do resultado </option>

    <option value="F">FEMININO</option>
    <option value="M">MASCULINO</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz o seguinte... não sei se é isso mas foi isso que eu entendi, você quer que venha selecionado o valor que está no seu banco... ficaria assim:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="ds_sexo"> Sexo</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="ds_sexo"id="ds_sexo">
    <option value="F"<?= $cliente->ds_sexo == 'F' ? ' selected' : ''?>>FEMININO</option>
    <option value="M"<?= $cliente->ds_sexo == 'M' ? ' selected' : ''?>>MASCULINO</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

não deixa de ser `if-else` só que ternário, mas funciona com qualquer um. =D

Comment: explendido!!!!!!!!!